# How to convert a Properties Object to Custom Object using Jackson?

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties, jackson, yaml

In a Spring Boot application, Spring Boot is used to build a Properties object from a YAML file as follows:

```java
YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yamlFactory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
yamlFactory.setResources(new DefaultResourceLoader().getResource("application.yml"));
Properties properties = yamlFactory.getObject();
```

The reason why Spring Boot's own parser is used is that it not only reads YAML-compliant settings, but also dot-notated properties like e.g:

```yaml
artist.elvis.name: "Elvis"
artist.elvis.message: "Aloha from Hawaii"
```

Now that the Properties object is built, I want to map it into an object like the following for example:

```java
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
private record Artist(Elvis elvis) {

    private record Elvis(String name, String message) { }
}
```

### My question is:

How can this be done with Jackson? Or is there another/better solution for this?

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw functionality like that in Ratpack framework.
e.g.:

```
        var propsFileUrl =
                Thread.currentThread()
                        .getContextClassLoader()
                        .getResource("application.properties");

        ApplicationProperties applicationProperties =
                ConfigData.builder()
                        .props(propsFileUrl)
                        .build()
                        .get(ApplicationProperties.class);
```

under the hood it is indeed done by using jackson's object mapper, but the logic is not as trivial to post it here.

here's the library:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.ratpack/ratpack-core/2.0.0-rc-1

Comment: Wow, didn't know about this framework/library. Seems to have some pretty cool stuff to offer ;). Can't say for now whether I'll go with their crazy get-the-job-done tools or dive deeper into their code to see how one can do the things I thought could be done with Jackson anyhow... +1

Comment: you're welcome)
https://pastebin.com/tsLRpurE - here's the parser I managed to extract from their code. may come in handy

Answer (score 0):

`application.yml` is the default yml file, so no custom configuration is required. [Value annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) should be able to read the properties.

```
@Value("${artist.elvis.name}")
private String name;
```

Next part I am not sure about your requirements, but hope this is what you are looking for.

To bind to this object 'constructor' can be a good option.
Class for elvis

```
@Bean
public class Elvis {
  private String name;
  private String message;

  public Elvis(@Value("${artist.elvis.name"}) final String name, @Value("${artist.elvis.message"}) final String message) {
     this.name=name;
     this.message=message
  }

  // getter setter for name and message
}
```

Now Autowire the created bean to Artist bean

```
@Bean("artists")
public class Artists {
  @Autowired
  private Elvis elvis
  
  pubic Elvis getElvis() {
    return elvis;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. But what I'm looking for is really a way to read in a yaml-file still before Spring Boot context ist set up and map it to an object. The yaml-file has both, valid yaml-structure and dot-notated properties inside. Spring Boot would read them correctly, but as mentioned, Spring Boot isn't available at the time when I need it. Thus, I have to parse myself.

Comment: I have not tested it but in case of `application.properties`, the above works properly. So I assumed it should work for yaml as well

Comment: Yes, it surely works, but not before Spring Boot's application context ist set up. During the startup phase, at a very early stage, e.g. when the Loggers are initialized, Spring Boot's magic features are not available. You have to rely on classic coding ;)

Comment: Actually, it worked for me even before the application context ist set up. Springboot maintains the dependency and waits till properties are loaded. So I would recommend testing if it works. Btw if it does not work, there are other solutions I will update the answer

Comment: Hi mahfuj asif, very nice of you to want to help. Log4j2 needs a connection-source for the JDBC appender during initialization. For this, a static factory method must be specified. So a static initializer must load the required connection data. And at this point, unfortunately, none of the Spring Boot tricks work. Even if I fill a static variable with values in PostConstruct, it is too late. Unfortunately, we are dealing with a classic boot-strapping problem. However, I am happy to hear further suggestions.